# Haproxy 1.5 504 Duplicate Orders Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

My HAProxy 1.5 load-balancer is occasionally getting 504 error from one either of the backend nodes. The 504 error is only specific to Woocommerce /checkout. The /checkout endpoint calls the payment gateway on the server side and Woocommerce captures the payment status and redirects the user to the thank you page.

In Woocommerce admin, there are duplicate orders from the same customer. I am suspecting it could be the one node timing out and passing the request to the next node while the transaction is still pending at the first node.

Here is an example of a 504 error. It seems there is waiting period of 8 mins (16:51 - 16:43).

```
Apr  1 16:43:47 LB1 haproxy[31955]: 115.66.152.19:28289 [01/Apr/2017:16:43:00.738] www-http m-backend/node2 46183/0/0/191/46374 200 1538 - - ---- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {http://<clientDomain>/checkout/} "POST /checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout HTTP/1.1"
Apr  1 16:52:05 LB1 haproxy[31955]: 115.66.152.19:11502 [01/Apr/2017:16:52:05.984] www-http m-backend/node2 0/0/0/5/5 200 202 - - ---- 3/3/1/1/0 0/0 {http://<clientDomain>/checkout/} "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1"
Apr  1 16:52:09 LB1 haproxy[31955]: 115.66.152.19:43861 [01/Apr/2017:16:51:09.123] www-http m-backend/node1 0/0/1/-1/60002 504 195 - - sH-- 2/2/0/0/0 0/0 {http://<clientDomain>/checkout/} "POST /checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout HTTP/1.1"
```

Another example:

```
Mar 31 13:05:04 LB1 haproxy[31955]: 222.164.62.123:52201 [31/Mar/2017:13:05:04.157] www-http m-backend/node2 0/0/1/142/143 200 1364 - - ---- 4/4/0/0/0 0/0 {http://<clientDomain>/checkout/} "POST /checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout HTTP/1.1"
Mar 31 13:06:18 LB1 haproxy[31955]: 222.164.62.123:52201 [31/Mar/2017:13:05:04.301] www-http m-backend/node1 14684/0/0/-1/74685 504 195 - - sH-- 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 {http://<clientDomain>/checkout/} "POST /checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout HTTP/1.1"
```

Two pairs of duplicate orders:

```
mysql> select * from wp_posts where ID in (468,469,470,471);
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| ID  | post_author | post_date           | post_date_gmt       | post_content | post_title                              | post_excerpt | post_status   | comment_status | ping_status | post_password       | post_name                   | to_ping | pinged | post_modified       | post_modified_gmt   | post_content_filtered | post_parent | guid                                                                | menu_order | post_type      | post_mime_type | comment_count |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| 468 |           X | 2017-03-31 21:09:24 | 2017-03-31 13:09:24 |              | Order &ndash; March 31, 2017 @ 09:09 PM |              | wc-processing | open           | closed      | order_58de5501aeffb | order-mar-31-2017-0109-pm   |         |        | 2017-03-31 21:09:24 | 2017-03-31 13:09:24 |                       |           0 | http://<clientDomain>/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=468 |          0 | shop_order |                |             2  |
| 469 |           X | 2017-03-31 21:10:01 | 2017-03-31 13:10:01 |              | Order &ndash; March 31, 2017 @ 09:10 PM |              | wc-processing | open           | closed      | order_58de5527335c1 | order-mar-31-2017-0109-pm-2 |         |        | 2017-03-31 21:10:01 | 2017-03-31 13:10:01 |                       |           0 | http://<clientDomain>/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=469 |          0 | shop_order |                |             2  |
| 470 |           X | 2017-04-02 00:55:21 | 2017-04-01 16:55:21 |              | Order &ndash; April 2, 2017 @ 12:55 AM  |              | wc-processing | open           | closed      | order_58dfdb75c2b0a | order-apr-01-2017-0455-pm   |         |        | 2017-04-02 00:55:21 | 2017-04-01 16:55:21 |                       |           0 | http://<clientDomain>/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=470 |          0 | shop_order |                |             2  |
| 471 |           X | 2017-04-02 00:56:28 | 2017-04-01 16:56:28 |              | Order &ndash; April 2, 2017 @ 12:56 AM  |              | wc-processing | open           | closed      | order_58dfdbba98bce | order-apr-01-2017-0456-pm   |         |        | 2017-04-02 00:56:28 | 2017-04-01 16:56:28 |                       |           0 | http://<clientDomain>/?post_type=shop_order&#038;p=471 |          0 | shop_order |                |             2  |
+-----+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------+-----------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

haproxy.cfg

```
global
    log /dev/log      local0
    log /dev/log      local1 notice
    #chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon

    # Default SSL material locations
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

    maxconn 3000
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

defaults
    log global
    mode        http
    option      httplog
    option      dontlognull
    option      forwardfor
    option      http-server-close
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000

    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth <user>:<password>

    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend www-http
    bind *:80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /home/lb1/ssl_certs/cert1.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    timeout client          1m
    default_backend m-backend
    capture request header Referer len 64

backend m-backend
    balance roundrobin
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout server          1m
    server node1      node1:80 check
    server node2      node2:80 check
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

Comment: Haproxy doesn't retry requests that have already been sent to a backend.  These are double-clicks from the browser.